# Active Directory Change Password and Deactivated Status

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I have a Powershell script which creates new Active Directory accounts in either an enabled or disabled state. When enabled, the user must change the password at next logon. When disabled, it removes this requirement. How can I create a disabled user with the box for must change password still checked? The option still needs to be checked as it is used for internal audits to detect tampering.

Code:

```
-Enabled $Decision -AccountPassword $Password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

$Status = $Line.'Account Status'
    $Decision = $false
    if ($Status -eq 'Enabled') { $Decision = $true }
```

Comment: Hi, you should include a bit more code (it seems truncated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this property after creating the (disabled) account:

```
#sample data
$lines = @(
    @{
        Name = "enabledUser"
        'Account Status' = "Enabled"
    },
    @{
        Name = "disabledUser"
        'Account Status' = "Disabled"
    }
)

foreach($line in $lines) {
    if($line.'Account Status' -eq "Enabled") {
        New-ADUser -Name $line.Name -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
            -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "p@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)
    } else {
        New-ADUser -Name $line.Name -Enabled $false `
            -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "p@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)            

        Set-ADUser $line.Name -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
    }
}
```